# Lag R data.table with a group condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have data like this:

```
test <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,1,5,5,5,6),
               time = c(0,1,4,5,6,7,9),
               cond = c("a","a","b","a","b","b","b"),
               value = c(5,3,2,4,0,3,1), 
               stringsAsFactors=F)

setDT(test)[,order := order(time),id][order(id,order)]

id time cond value order
1  0    a    5     1
2  1    a    3     1
1  4    b    2     2
5  5    a    4     1
5  6    b    0     2
5  7    b    3     3
6  9    b    1     1
```

The data.table function creates a column "order" which is the order of time based on the group id.

I would like to create a column which returns the previous value but only where the condition is "b".  If the condition is "a" return the current value and if the condition is "b" and the previous is "b" then skip to the next non "b".  If the first condition of a group is "b" Then return NA.

Desired output would be like this:

```
id time cond value order prev
1  0    a    5     1     5
2  1    a    3     1     3
1  4    b    2     2     5
5  5    a    4     1     4
5  6    b    0     2     4
5  7    b    3     3     4
6  9    b    1     1     NA
```

I've tried some functions like this but only returned NAs.

```
test[, prev := shift(value[cond == 'b']), .(id,order)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, one option could be:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(test)[, order := order(time), id][order(id, order)]

test[, prev := {
  frst <- ifelse(cond[1] == "a", value[1],
                 ifelse(cond[1] == "b", NA, cond[1]))

  prev <- as.integer(ifelse(cond == "b" & shift(cond) == "b",
                            NA,
                            c(frst, shift(value)[-1])))

}, by = id][cond == "b", prev := zoo::na.locf(prev), by = id]
```

Output:

```
   id time cond value order prev
1:  1    0    a     5     1    5
2:  1    4    b     2     2    5
3:  2    1    a     3     1    3
4:  5    5    a     4     1    4
5:  5    6    b     0     2    4
6:  5    7    b     3     3    4
7:  6    9    b     1     1   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the non-b values first, `zoo:na.locf` can do the rest (fill the b (NA) values downwards).

```
library(zoo)
test[cond != 'b', prev := value]
test[, prev := na.locf(prev), id]

test
#    id time cond value order prev
# 1:  1    0    a     5     1    5
# 2:  2    1    a     3     1    3
# 3:  1    4    b     2     2    5
# 4:  5    5    a     4     1    4
# 5:  5    6    b     0     2    4
# 6:  5    7    b     3     3    4
# 7:  6    9    b     1     1   NA
```